# Finding weakly connected components in Memgraph graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-databases, memgraphdb

Does Memgraph have and algorithm for finding weakly connected components in graphs? I couldn't find it among [Memgraph built-in algorithms](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms) or [MAGE algorithms](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/algorithms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `weakly_connected_components` query modules. Memgraph comes with NetworkX library. NetworkX is a Python package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.

You can call it with the following command:

```
CALL weakly_connected_components.get()
YIELD node, component_id;
```

The complete documentation is available on the [Memgraph website](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/cpp/weakly-connected-components).